# (Nexus 5X, Marshmellow) Gmail app: how to see separate notifications for each new email?

Tags: notifications, gmail

I have a Nexus 5x with Android Marshmellow. The Gmail notification I see on my locked screen groups all the messages together and shows "5 new messages". Can I see each new email as separate notification, (so, 5 notifications)so that I can know who sent the mail, the subject etc. instead of only knowing that there are 5 messages?

I recently moved from iOS and missing that feature. Thanks!

Comment: I think you would have to switch to a third-party lock screen app. See if this helps: http://phandroid.com/2014/03/08/how-to-get-ios-lock-screen-on-android/

Comment: @Ron You can also hold and swipe down the single notification to see the other details you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @Lucky's solution is pretty close to what I wanted to achieve. Thanks for this helpful suggestion!

Comment: @Ron Cool. That's not just for Gmail. That's how Android notifications usually work. Notifications from the same app merge into a single notifying which don't cluster your notification bar. You could try the same on other apps too. And sometimes it works on single notifications too.